# How to call scala main function with argument in zeppelin notebook

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am executing scala object in zeppelin notebook as follows but getting error.

[image]

Comment: Can you try `Foo.main("world")` in the second sheet?

Comment: Please don't post code or error text as images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi it worked as follows,

Foo.main(Array("Ram"))

Output:Hello,Ram